# zeroclipboard is not working version2.1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, zeroclipboard

I am trying to use zeroclipboard 2.1.1

I added the zeroclipboard.js and the zeroclipboard.sw but when I click on the button nothing becomes copy.
though when I right click on the button, the flash player setting appears.

any help?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var client = new ZeroClipboard(document.getElementById("Button2"));

client.on("ready", function (readyEvent) {
     alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

    client.on("aftercopy", function (event) {
        // `this` === `client`
        // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
        //event.target.disabled = true;
        //alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"]);
    });

    client.on('error', function (event) {
         console.log( 'ZeroClipboard error of type "' + event.name + '": ' + event.message );
        ZeroClipboard.destroy();
    });
});
});
```

this alert `alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );` is not showing

I already added the jquery 2.1

Answer (score 0):

I just figured this out.. the flash element needs to be clicked in order to copy. For me the element was being added about 10 pixels offset from my actual button, thus never being clicked. Use css to absolutely position it over the button and it should work for you! (hours of frustration for this? terrible documentation!)

You also need to do this to add the movie and make sure your Zeroclipboard.js is being included

```
              ZeroClipboard.config({ 
              swfPath: moviepath,
              forceHandCursor: true});
```